# Find a combination of "word:otherword" in textfile with grep with colon

Tags: regex, grep, pattern-matching, text-files

It's not much but I didn't find a solution by searching here or experimenting with a regex-generator:

I want to search for lines in a textfile containing

`due:Mo, due:Di, ... or due:So`

Maybe I'm near the solution with

`grep "due:+(Mo\|Di\|Mi\|Do\|Fr)" todo.txt --color=auto`

But this one just highlights and searches for the 5 days (German days of the week). Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are really close, in a POSIX BRE pattern, the `(` and `)` capturing parentheses should be escaped and you do not need the `+` quantifier (that is actually parsed as a literal  `+` symbol in your POSIX BRE pattern) after `:`:

```
grep "due:\(Mo\|Di\|Mi\|Do\|Fr\)\>"
```

I also suggest a word boundary check with `\>`.

You may get rid of some escapes using a POSIX ERE with `-E` option:

```
grep -E "due:(Mo|Di|Mi|Do|Fr)\>"
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/i2Xs68).

Comment: Great. Another step in using CLI. :) Thank you.

Comment: @TravelTrader Please consider accepting if it worked for you.

Comment: Is there a possibility to search for the whole string but only mark the 2 letters after `due:` with the option `--color=auto`?

Comment: Only with a PCRE pattern, `grep -P "(?<=due:)(?:Mo|Di|Mi|Do|Fr)\b" `

Comment: Great. First it doesn't work but with `brew install grep` I have the right version on my macOS using `ggrep` instead of `grep`. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @TravelTrader Next time, mention the OS you are using `grep` in. It make a huge difference. On Solaris OS, `grep` functionality is even poorer, and on MacOS, installing GNU `grep` with `brew` is a common workaround when you need to get the most from `grep`.